# soap-XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document

Tags: xml, soap

i am creating simple web service using soap.i keep get at this error "XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document" when trying to run the soap client. here is my code

server:

```
<?php
class Member extends CI_Controller
{ 
    function Member()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $ns = 'http://192.168.19.25/xampp/CodeIgniter/index.php/member';
        // load nusoap toolkit library in controller
        $this->load->library("nusoap_library"); 
        // create soap server object
        $this->nusoap_server = new soap_server(); 
        // wsdl cinfiguration
        $this->nusoap_server->configureWSDL("SOAP Server Using NuSOAP in CodeIgniter", $ns); 
        // server namespace
        $this->nusoap_server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $ns; 
        // "addnumbers" method parameters
        $input_array = array ('a' => "xsd:string", 'b' => "xsd:string"); 
        $return_array = array ("return" => "xsd:string");
        $this->nusoap_server->register(
            'addnumbers', 
            $input_array, 
            $return_array, 
            "urn:SOAPServerWSDL", 
            "urn:".$ns."/addnumbers", 
            "rpc", 
            "encoded", 
            "Addition Of Two Numbers"
       );
    }

    function index()
    {
        function addnumbers($a,$b)
        {
            $c = $a + $b;
            return $c;
        }
        $this->nusoap_server->service(file_get_contents("php://input")); 
       // read raw data from request body
    }
}
?>
```